# Texbox area is not visible in Safari and iPhone web browsers

Tags: ios, reactjs, textarea

I am testing a react application and I was checking the app in iPhone-mobile browsers, however, I noticed that there is a text area which appears invisible in all web browsers for iOS (works perfectly fine in Android).

I checked on a Mac using Safari and it has the same issue, it does however work in `Mac - Chrome`. **Does anyone know why could this be happening? For some reason it just does not work in iOS web browsers** (Safari, Chrome, Brave...)

The only difference I was able to observe between Chrome and Safari is that when I inspect the text area in Safari I get to see **Shadow content(User agent)** , **Chrome does not have this.**